# Java - Intercept two collections and get the remaining elements

Tags: java, collections

I have two collections of Strings in java:

```
A: ("abc", "bcd" "cde")
B: ("abc", "cde")
```

I pretend to get a new collection that contains all elements that are in A and are not in B, in math something like: C = A\B

In this case C would be something like:

```
C: ("bcd")
```

How could this be done efficiently in java using collections?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Collection's  [removeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-)

```
// before a contained ["abc", "bcd" "cde"]
a.removeAll(b)
// now a contains ["abc", "bcd" "cde"]
```

if you do not want `a` to change, I'd recommend doing a deep copy of `a` into a new variable first `c`